# fail2ban stops logging after some time (3-4 days)

Tags: logs, jails, fail2ban

I've noticed that whenever I want to see fail2ban logs after 3 or 4 days of being working, it compresses the logs to .gz which Im fine with that:

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root   root      90034 May  1 12:49 dmesg.old
-rw-------. 1 root   root          0 Jun 14 03:13 fail2ban.log
-rw-------. 1 root   root       8974 May 24 02:22 fail2ban.log-20150524.gz
-rw-------. 1 root   root         20 May 24 03:44 fail2ban.log-20150601.gz
-rw-------. 1 root   root         20 Jun  1 03:30 fail2ban.log-20150607.gz
-rw-------. 1 root   root       4785 Jun 14 03:10 fail2ban.log-20150614.gz
```

The problem is that it stops working like you can see in my main fail2ban.log it has 0 bytes and nothing inside of it.

I was thinking that probably fail2ban has nothing to log but I see the secure log and I see the following:

```
Jun 18 09:24:52 localserver sshd[9641]: input_userauth_request: invalid user Exit [preauth]
Jun 18 09:24:53 localserver sshd[9641]: Connection closed by 123.56.112.165 [preauth]
Jun 18 10:03:19 localserver sshd[10218]: Invalid user alina from 123.56.112.165
Jun 18 10:03:19 localserver sshd[10218]: input_userauth_request: invalid user alina [preauth]
Jun 18 10:03:20 localserver sshd[10218]: Connection closed by 123.56.112.165 [preauth]
Jun 18 10:11:24 localserver sshd[10329]: Invalid user kadmin from 173.201.39.212
Jun 18 10:11:24 localserver sshd[10329]: input_userauth_request: invalid user kadmin [preauth]
Jun 18 10:11:24 localserver sshd[10329]: Received disconnect from 173.201.39.212: 11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Jun 18 10:11:24 localserver sshd[10331]: Received disconnect from 173.201.39.212: 11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Jun 18 10:11:25 localserver sshd[10333]: Invalid user guest from 173.201.39.212
Jun 18 10:11:25 localserver sshd[10333]: input_userauth_request: invalid user guest [preauth]
Jun 18 10:11:25 localserver sshd[10333]: Received disconnect from 173.201.39.212: 11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Jun 18 10:11:25 localserver sshd[10335]: Invalid user pi from 173.201.39.212
Jun 18 10:11:25 localserver sshd[10335]: input_userauth_request: invalid user pi [preauth]
Jun 18 10:11:25 localserver sshd[10335]: Received disconnect from 173.201.39.212: 11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Jun 18 10:11:26 localserver sshd[10337]: Invalid user ubnt from 173.201.39.212
Jun 18 10:11:26 localserver sshd[10337]: input_userauth_request: invalid user ubnt [preauth]
Jun 18 10:11:26 localserver sshd[10337]: Received disconnect from 173.201.39.212: 11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Jun 18 10:11:26 localserver sshd[10339]: Invalid user xbian from 173.201.39.212
Jun 18 10:11:26 localserver sshd[10339]: input_userauth_request: invalid user xbian [preauth]
Jun 18 10:11:26 localserver sshd[10339]: Received disconnect from 173.201.39.212: 11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Jun 18 10:11:26 localserver sshd[10341]: Invalid user admin from 173.201.39.212
Jun 18 10:11:26 localserver sshd[10341]: input_userauth_request: invalid user admin [preauth]
Jun 18 10:11:27 localserver sshd[10341]: Received disconnect from 173.201.39.212: 11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Jun 18 10:42:29 localserver sshd[10741]: Invalid user andrei from 123.56.112.165
Jun 18 10:42:29 localserver sshd[10741]: input_userauth_request: invalid user andrei [preauth]
Jun 18 10:42:29 localserver sshd[10741]: Connection closed by 123.56.112.165 [preauth]
```

Which makes me mad because attacks are still in place and fail2ban is doing nothing about it. I checked if fail2ban is still working and seems to me like it is:

```
sudo fail2ban-client status
Status
|- Number of jail:  1
`- Jail list:   ssh-iptables
```

I made sure also that the logpath is correct:

```
# Jail for more extended banning of persistent abusers
# !!! WARNING !!!
#   Make sure that your loglevel specified in fail2ban.conf/.local
#   is not at DEBUG level -- which might then cause fail2ban to fall into
#   an infinite loop constantly feeding itself with non-informative lines
[recidive]

logpath  = /var/log/fail2ban.log
port     = all
protocol = all
bantime  = 604800  ; 1 week
findtime = 86400   ; 1 day
maxretry = 5
```

`sudo fail2ban-client status ssh-iptables` gives the following:

```
Status for the jail: ssh-iptables
|- Filter
|  |- Currently failed: 0
|  |- Total failed: 1089
|  `- File list:    /var/log/secure
`- Actions
   |- Currently banned: 0
   |- Total banned: 137
   `- Banned IP list:
```

Any other idea that can help me to fix this problem?

Comment: That `fail2ban-client status` only shows you that you have one jail.  Run `sudo fail2ban-client status ssh-iptables` to see if that particular jail is banning attackers.

Comment: Thank you @garethTheRed this is what I get `Status for the jail: ssh-iptables
|- Filter
|  |- Currently failed: 0
|  |- Total failed: 1089
|  `- File list: /var/log/secure
`- Actions
   |- Currently banned: 0
   |- Total banned: 137
   `- Banned IP list: `

Comment: You'll need to try that command a few times to confirm that nothing is being banned (you could have run the above at a moment when nothing was failed/banned).  Also, it's better to edit your answer with the result of the command as it's easier to read. You can run the server in the foreground (see `man fail2ban-server`), although you'd of course need to do that for 3-4 days.  Consider running it with `screen` or `tmux`.

Comment: @Vato I'm having this issue also. Did you ever find a fix?